# Integrating Electron Builder with React resulting in bigger app

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to integrate Electron Builder with React (create-react-app).

Currently my react code and my electron code are separate projects, and work fine, but I'd rather integrate them properly to speed up the build process.

At present, I build the React app, and use a postbuild script to copy the built files to a directory in my electron app. I then build the electron app, pointing the url to this directory.

When I tried integrating, I assumed I should set up my scripts to build the React app first and then build the Electron app, again pointing to the React directory. However, the compiled app is twice the size of before (280mb vs 150mb), and takes longer for Electron Builder to package.

Is Electron Builder doing some automatic magic with React and resulting in 2 React builds, or something like that? Or is it compiling all of the NPM modules for React into the Electron project, or something similar? I can't really work out why this is happening, but it seems like my understanding of the build steps is obviously wrong somewhere.

Thanks!